# UI state vs Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

So my application has 3 drop-downs, a pagination component and a table.

Two drop-downs receive their options from rest call.

eg: State and City.

Based on the state selection the city dropdown makes rest call to fetch city.

Based on the selection made in the drop-downs the data in the table updates by making rest call.

The react.org example talks about lifting the state up. Hence the parent component which displays all the three drop-downs and table maintains the state of keeping track of which state, city and date is selected and what is the data that is being displayed in the table. Every-time the dropdown selection changes the parent state updates and re-fetches the new data.
Also the the table data updates every few seconds by sending the selected 
state, city and date.

The question that I have is should the rest call to fetch the information regarding the dropdown options be in parent component or respective drop down components so that I can reuse the drop down in other page and do I need the dropdown to have there own state to keep track what is the selected value?

Answer (score 0):

> Should the rest call to fetch the information regarding the dropdown
>   options ?

The rest call to fetch the data should be part of the parent component only. 
It makes sense to keep the dropdown component as a pure component which receives the options values as props from it's parent.

Following this method would really make your dropdown component as reusable component who only job is display the options and pass back the selected value to it's parent  via a callback function passed as prop to the dropdown component.

> Do I need the dropdown to have there own state to keep track what is
>   the selected value?

No, you can pass the selected value back to the parent using a callback function.

Some Code

```
Parent Component -->

constructor(){
    this.state = {
        stateOptions: null,
        cityOptions: null,
        selectedState: null,
        selectedCity: null 
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    fetch.state.api => {
        this.setState({
            stateOptions: stateDataFromApi
        })
    }
}

handleStateSelection = (selectedState) => {
    fetch.city.api => {
        this.setState({
            selectedState: selectedState,
            cityOptions: cityDataFromApi
        })
    }
}

handleCitySelection = (selectedCity) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedCity: selectedCity
    })
}


<div className="parentComponent">
    <Dropdown 
        type="state" 
        handleStateSelection="this.handleStateSelection"
        data={this.state.stateOptions}
    />
    <Dropdown 
        type="city" 
        handleStateSelection="this.handleCitySelection"
        data={this.state.cityOptions}
    />
    <Table data={this.tableData} />
    ..
    ..
</div>
```

Comment: What if a HOC is used for both the drop-downs and that HOC has the state with the dropdown options.Basically moving the state options and city options to the HOC.Also creating a HOC for the table component and the parent component just maintains the state that is passed between the child components? For eg: When the city changes the HOC state updates and the table HOC receives this as a prop and make the rest call to fetch the new table data.

Comment: With the approach that you suggested I can make only the dropdown a reusable UI component but what if I want to make the UI + rest end point as a usable dropdown component.Say for example I want to import state dropdown in two different parent components but i don't want to specify the rest url in both parents. The state dropdown will always know from where to fetch the options.

Comment: @Neha, this depends on the use case again, if every dropdown you are going to use in the application will get it's data from the api you might wanna take the HOC approach.